# How can I pass the selected date(value) from react calendar to another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar

I am trying to pass the selected date to a component that contains the booking component and reservation button. I need the selected date for the axios call. This is what the Booking component looks like:

```
function Booking() {
  const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());
  const disabledDates = [
    new Date(2021, 8, 13),
    new Date(2021, 8, 16),
  ];
  console.log(value);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Calendar
          onChange={onChange}
          value={value}
          maxDetail="month"
          minDetail="month"
          tileDisabled={({date, view}) =>
          (view === 'month') && // Block day tiles only
          disabledDates.some(disabledDate =>
            (date.getFullYear() === disabledDate.getFullYear() &&
            date.getMonth() === disabledDate.getMonth() &&
            date.getDate() === disabledDate.getDate()) 
          )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Booking;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the state to the outer component, and make it a prop of the Booking component.

```
function Booking({value, setValue}) {
  
  const disabledDates = [
    new Date(2021, 8, 13),
    new Date(2021, 8, 16),
  ];
  console.log(value);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Calendar
          onChange={setValue}
          value={value}
          maxDetail="month"
          minDetail="month"
          tileDisabled={({date, view}) =>
          (view === 'month') && // Block day tiles only
          disabledDates.some(disabledDate =>
            (date.getFullYear() === disabledDate.getFullYear() &&
            date.getMonth() === disabledDate.getMonth() &&
            date.getDate() === disabledDate.getDate()) 
          )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Booking;
```

and in your outer component do something like this:

```
function OuterComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(new Date());

  ...whatever else it needs to do
  
  return (<Booking value={value} setValue={setValue}/>
          ...whatever else it needs to contain
          );
}
```

Comment: It says that value has already been declared in Booking.js

Comment: I deleted the line where I declared it. But now it says: onChange is not defined

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about using a global state approach? Using maybe with React Context to centralize state and functions that change your state.

Something like:

```js
// dateContext
import React, {craetContext, useState} from 'react'

export const DateContext = createContext({})

const DateProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())
  
  <DateContext.Provider value={date, setDate}>{children}<DateContext.Provider)
}

export default DateProvider;

// Wrap your components with DateProvider like: 

<DateProvider>
 <Booking />
 <OtherComponent />
</DateProvider>

// to use in your components you can do this way:

// Booking component

import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {DateContext} from 'your_path';

function Booking() {

  const {date, setDate} = useContext(DateContext)
  
  const disabledDates = [
    new Date(2021, 8, 13),
    new Date(2021, 8, 16),
  ];
  console.log(value);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Calendar
          onChange={setDate}
          value={date}
          maxDetail="month"
          minDetail="month"
          tileDisabled={({date1, view}) =>
          (view === 'month') && // Block day tiles only
          disabledDates.some(disabledDate =>
            (date1.getFullYear() === disabledDate.getFullYear() &&
            date1.getMonth() === disabledDate.getMonth() &&
            date1.getDate() === disabledDate.getDate()) 
          )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Booking;
```

This is only a code snippet. You'll need to implement it in your way.